# Printing out the payload for an Apache HttpClient PostMethod call

Tags: groovy, apache-commons-httpclient

I am making an HTTP Post request to a url using Apache HttpClient 3.1 where I am passing a JSON request entity and some parameters like so..

```
    HttpMethod method = new PostMethod("https://starfleet.reliant/commandConsole")
   // assume there is already a varaible json which has valid JSON in it
    StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(json.toString(), "application/json", "UTF-8")
    method.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
    method.addParameter("format","json");
    method.addParameter("prefixCode","16309");
```

Is there a way I can print out what the entire payload looks like (including the JSON request entity and the parameters)? In other words I want to see exactly what is being posted to the server.

If I just do...

```
println("Sending this ${method.toString()}")
```

This just prints...

```
  Sending this org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@3f67dcc1
```

which of course is not what I want.

Comment: Extend PostMethod and add your own toString()

Comment: @Joseph, there's gotta be an easier way!

Answer (score 2):

For HttpClient 3x:

Try Using an Object Mapper like this for requestentity:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(requestEntity));
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For HttpClient 4x+:
Try checking out `EntityUtils` from apache [(documented here)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html)

It will be something like this

```
String str = EntityUtils.toString(method.getRequestEntity());
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think this only works with apache httpclient 4.0+ but I am stuck with 3 and its a pain to upgrade.

Comment: correct..its worth upgrading though..updated answer..it will print your request entity in string format like json..eg:`{"content":"{\"a\":\"b\"}","charset":"UTF-8","contentType":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","contentLength":9,"repeatable":true}`